# How to get updated multi-select dropdown data within same form

Tags: javascript, php, bootstrap-4

My application uses bootstrap,js,php. I used bootstrap to get the multiselect dropdown. Adding data for the first time works fine. When someone clicks on edit(a button in my application), I can retrieve the information from database and get the preselected data same as first time. Now if the user changes the selection, I am not able to get it working. I could fetch data to js variable but issue in setting it to html id. It becomes null. If I can't assign to html id, I cannot get it php to use.

```
$(function(){
    // $('.multi').multiselect("refresh");
    var brands;// = $('#pSpecial option:selected');
    var specials;// = [];
    $('.multi').multiselect({
        includeSelectAllOption:true,
        enableCaseInsensitiveFiltering: true,
        enableFiltering:true,
        maxHeight: '275',
        buttonWidth: '180',
        onChange: function(element, checked) {
            brands = $('#pSpecial option:selected');
            specials = [];
            $(brands).each(function(brand){
                specials.push([$(this).val()]);
            });
            console.log(specials);
            alert(specials);
            $("#pSpecial").val(specials);
            alert(document.getElementById('pSpecial').value);
        }
    });
    $('.multi').multiselect("refresh");
});
```

My code has no syntax error. it fails to execute `$("#pSpecial").val(specials);`

Comment: is ` alert(specials);` working?

Comment: Yes it is working @KunalRaut.